# Extracting top-N occurrences in a grouped dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to find out the top-3 highest frequency restaurant names under each type of restaurant

[image]

The columns are:

`rest_type` - Column for the type of restaurant

`name` - Column for the name of the restaurant

`url` - Column used for counting occurrences

This was the code that ended up working for me after some searching:

```
df_1=df.groupby(['rest_type','name']).agg('count')
datas=df_1.groupby(['rest_type'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x.sort_values(by="url",ascending=False).head(3))
['url'].reset_index().rename(columns={'url':'count'})
```

The final output was as follows:

[image]

I had a few questions pertaining to the above code:

How are we able to groupby using `rest_type` again for datas variable after grouping it earlier. Should it not give the missing column error? The second groupby operation is a bit confusing to me.

What does the first formulated column `level_0` signify? I tried the code with `as_index=True` and it created an index and column pertaining to `rest_type` so I couldn't reset the index. Output below:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please share a sample of your original `df` for a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: From MRE, *"DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code."* and read https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15239951

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` a second time as it is present in the index which is recognized by [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

`level_0` comes from the `reset_index` command because you index is unnamed.

That said, and provided I understand your dataset, I feel that you could achieve your goal more easily:

```
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'rest_type': random.choices('ABCDEF', k=20),
                   'name': random.choices('abcdef', k=20),
                   'url': range(20), # looks like this is a unique identifier
                  })

def tops(s, n=3):
    return s.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(n)

df.groupby('rest_type')['name'].apply(tops, n=3)
```

edit: here is an alternative to format the result as a dataframe with informative column names

```
(df.groupby('rest_type')
   .apply(lambda x: x['name'].value_counts().nlargest(3))
   .reset_index().rename(columns={'name': 'counts', 'level_1': 'name'})
)
```

Comment: @Naman Sood: did the proposed solution work for you? If not can you give some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case where the above query looks working partially. In my case the cooccurrence value is coming as 1 always.
Here in my input data frame.
[image]

And my query is below

`top_five_family_cooccurence_df = (common_top25_cooccurance1_df.groupby('family') .apply(lambda x: x['related_family'].value_counts().nlargest(5)) .reset_index().rename(columns={'related_family': 'cooccurence', 'level_1': 'related_family'}) )`

I am getting result as
[image]

Where as The cooccurrence is always giving me 1.

Comment: I am expecting a result along with the cooccurrence count. Any help.?